# directive $compile issue with wrapper HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I am trying to create a directive that if I declare:

```
<input my-directive show-button-bar="true" ng-model="fooBar"\>
```

It will create the following HTML:

```
<div on-toggle="toggled(open)" is-open="dpModel.displayDatePicker" dropdown="" class="btn-group ng-scope">
  <input my-directive show-button-bar="true" ng-model="fooBar"\>
  <ul ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class="dropdown-menu datepicker-popup dropdown-menu-right">
    <div ng-if="showButtonBar">
      <div role="group" class="btn-group pull-left">
        <button ng-click="setToday()" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" type="button">Today</button>
        <button ng-click="clear()" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button">Clear</button>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="toggled(false)" class="btn btn-xs pull-right btn-success" type="button">Done</button>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the snippet of code from my directive where I try to achieve this:

```
var dropdown = $compile(angular.element('<div class=\"btn-group\" dropdown is-open=\"dpModel.displayDatePicker\" on-toggle=\"toggled(open)\"/>'))(scope);

var ulTemplate = '<ul id=\"list2\"ng-if=\"showButtonBar\" class=\"dropdown-menu datepicker-popup\" ng-class=\"direction === \'right\' ? \'dropdown-menu-right\':\'dropdown-menu-left\'\" role=\"menu\" ng-click=\"$event.stopPropagation()\">' +
                '<li ng-if=\"dpModel.displayDatePicker\">' +
                '<datepicker ng-model=\"dpModel.value\" show-weeks=\"false\"></datepicker>' +
                '</li>' +
                '<div ng-if=\"showButtonBar\">' +
                '<div class=\"btn-group pull-left\" role=\"group\">' +
                '<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-info\" ng-click=\"setToday()\">Today</button>' +
                '<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\" ng-click=\"clear()\">Clear</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs pull-right btn-success\" ng-click=\"toggled(false)\">Done</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</ul>';
var ul = $compile(angular.element(ulTemplate))(scope);
element.wrap(dropdown);
ul.insertAfter(element);
```

The problem I am having is the ul portion

```
var ul = $compile(angular.element(ulTemplate)(scope))
```

will compile with the scope properly but the wrapper portion `dropdown` does not get the scope properly.  How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

UPDATED:
Forgot to also mention that I need to have an ng-model on the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit]

There was an error in the first example. It should be $attrs.$attr[this.name] not $attrs[this.name].
Here is a cleaner returning example using the template return function:
http://jsfiddle.net/numtpyL7/2/

```
module.directive('myDirective', function () {

    var wrapperTemplate = '\
<div>\
    <ul>\
        <li>Some Text</li>\
    </ul>\
</div>';

    return {
        template: function($element, $attrs) {
            var directiveTag = $attrs.$attr[this.name];
            var inputElem = $element.clone().removeAttr(directiveTag);
            var replacementHtml = angular.element(wrapperTemplate);
            replacementHtml.prepend(inputElem);

            return replacementHtml[0].outerHTML;
        },
        replace: true,
        priority: 999999
    };

});
```

[Original]

Using $compile in a high priority terminal directive is the way to go for something like this.
Being high priority and terminal means that it will run first on the element and nothing below it will run. Then in the directive compile code you remove that directive from the element, wrapped it with new DOM, and replace the current element with it.

```
module.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {

    var wrapperTemplate = '\
    <div on-toggle="toggled(open)" is-open="dpModel.displayDatePicker" dropdown="" class="btn-group ng-scope">\
        <ul ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class="dropdown-menu datepicker-popup dropdown-menu-right">\
            <div ng-if="showButtonBar">\
                <div role="group" class="btn-group pull-left">\
                    <button ng-click="setToday()" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" type="button">Today</button>\
                    <button ng-click="clear()" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button">Clear</button>\
                </div>\
                <button ng-click="toggled(false)" class="btn btn-xs pull-right btn-success" type="button">Done</button>\
            </div>\
        </ul>\
    </div>';

    return {
        terminal: true,
        priority: 999999,
        compile: function($element, $attrs) {
            // Remove this directive from the new wrapped template so that it does not get run again.
            var inputElement = $element.removeAttr($attrs.$attr[this.name]);

            // Add the new template to the DOM and remove the DOM of the current directive
            var replacementHtml = angular.element(wrapperTemplate).prepend(inputElement.clone());
            $element.after(replacementHtml);
            $element.remove();

            var subLink = $compile(replacementHtml);
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    subLink(scope);
                },
                post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                }
            }
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: This seems like the type of approach I was looking to take.  However when I run that code for some reason it gets in some infinite loop of some kind when prepending the inputElement.  It just keeps crashing my browser, but when I remove the ".prepend(inputElement.clone())" it stops the infinite loop.  Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because inside the `.wrap()` the dropdown element is cloned. While it's still bound to the scope, this has no effect on internal expressions and directives  and must be recompiled. The easier solution is to create a wrapping `<my-directive>` so that dropdown becomes the topmost element in this structure. `input` may be inserted using transclude.

```
<div my-directive><input show-button-bar="true"></div>

//within directive
return {
  transclude: true,
  template: '<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="dpModel.displayDatePicker" on-toggle="toggled(open)">' +
              '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
              '<ul ...></ul>' + // UL template goes here
            '</div>',
  link: function (scope, element) {
    //... link function code
  } 
}
```

And it seems that you don't need to compile in this case.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me due to the lack of access to the ng-model on my input.

Comment: Hmm, ng-model should be accessible from the directive?